# While Loop - Inaccurate total count of negative integers

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, sum

I'm supposed to write a code that exits when 0 is entered. Then find the sum of numbers entered and the amount of positive, negative integers. I can't figure out how to make the total count of negative integers right. What could be wrong?

```
num = 0
total = 0
pos = 0
neg = 0
L = []

while(True):
    num = int(input('Enter the number(If you enter 0, the program quits) : '))
    if num == 0:
        break
    L.append(num)
    total += num
    num += 1
    if num >= 0:
        pos += 1
    else:
        neg += 1
print('Entered numbers:', L)
print('Total : %d, Positive numbers : %d, Negative numbers : %d' % (total, pos, neg))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add example input, the generated output, and what the output should be.

Comment: `total` should be correct.  Can you give an example of the error?

Comment: `num += 1` Why are you adding 1 to num?  If the user enters -1 and then you add 1 to it, it is now 0 and will be counted as a positive number...

Comment: 2 Test runs both produced the right result. Please provide data that produced an error. Nicely done providing runnable code. :)

Comment: I think that's what caused the error. Thanks for pointing it out! @JohnGordon

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I must've mistaken total for negative numbers.. edited it! @Carl_M

Comment: Is my code is unnecessarily long & complicated?  @Carl_M

Comment: In my opinion, the code is fine. However, `num=0` can be removed. `num` is initialized each time in the loop. Not sure if `num += 1` is needed. I removed it for one test and there was no issue detected. There is a term called "pythonic" code, which you will learn with experience.  Use full words or multiple words for variables number, positive_numbers, negative_numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the if-else above the `num += 1` line or else when you calculate the positive or negative numbers, num has been changed to another value. The code should be like this:

```
L.append(num)
total += num
if num >= 0:
    pos += 1
else:
    neg += 1
num += 1
```

Comment: What happens if I don't change the order but change num += 1 to num += 0? The code worked but will it cause other errors?

Comment: Yes, You can also skip the num +=0 line. The code will work.